# App new version update does not show up on Google play

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have released a new version of my app but update for new version does not show up on Google Play on Huawei P20 8.1.0 while it can be updated on Sony E6883 with 7.1.1 Android version. Here is the changes in build.gradle:

Previously:

```
compileSdkVersion = 26
buildToolsVersion = "25.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 16

    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 42
    versionName "2.5.14"
```

Here is the latest version of the app:

```
compileSdkVersion = 28
buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 16

    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 43
    versionName "2.5.15"
}
```

What should have been changed after migrating it to API 28 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason and it might be useful for others who face this problem. I needed to clear Google Play Store app's cache both on my test devices :)

To do this:

Go to Settings > Apps & Notifications > Apps > Google Play Store > Uninstall Updates / Clear Cache (depending on your device)

You might need to do it for Google Play Services app as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clearing cache in Play Store can resolve the issue i guess.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already found that it was the solution.

Comment: Awesome. All the best @BakiKocak

Answer (score 0):

Has this issue been going on for days now? Google play does not update at the same time on every phone

Comment: It has been like 16 hours and I started to think that it might be available to be updated on API 28 as if it was first release for this particular Android versions. No luck on another device with 8.0.0.

Comment: I own a Huawei P20. I'll try searching for your app and see if I can see the latest update

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! The problem was a Google Play App's cache. I just cleared it :)